# How to rig two separate characters without linking them

Tags: rigging

I have 2 characters. I started with the human first. I added an armature, generated a rig, and parented the mesh to rig with automatic weights. Doing ok so far. I wanted to rig my other character too before i start animating. I just did all the steps again but i dont understand why my rig is linking the 2 meshes. Please help

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating two or more different Rigify armatures into the same .blend file, you should use the advanced options, to give to every piece of the rig an unique name and avoid unexpected behaviours due to name conflicts or datablocks overwritng.

[image]

Comment: Thank youuuuuu I kinda feel dumb there HAHAHAHA